# Nginx proxy Php-fpm7.2 + remote static files

Tags: php, nginx, proxy

I am trying to serve a web application that use php with symfony dependencies.

I use a nginx as a proxy to redirect to the appropriate app and server.
I succeeded to link nginx proxy php-fpm tcp socket. But I still have an issue. Before going further see my nginx proxy configuration.

```
upstream myapp {
    server mydomain.com:80 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myapp.mydomain.com;
    return       301 https://myapp.mydomain.com.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  myapp.mydomain.com;
    root         /var/www/myapp/public;


    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/wildcard.mydomain.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/wildcard.mydomain.com.key;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.mydomain.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.mydomain.com.error.log error;
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    client_max_body_size 256m;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://myapp/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        auth_basic           "Please authenticate";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/passwords/myapp.mydomain.com.passwdfile;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;        


    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass XX.XX.XX.XX:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
}
```

It's really weird because when I set `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;` php is responding but I have a 404 on all remote static files. When not set I perfectly get static files but cannot found index.php.

I surely miss some configuration on the proxy but I do not get it.

Comment: `try_files` is for local files only, so it always fails for your remote files and goes to `/index.php` instead.

Comment: Hmmm okay but could I do the same for remote ? Is I delete this it never goes to index.php

Comment: Do you want to divert to `index.php` if the remote server returns `404`? You could try `proxy_intercept_errors on; error_page 404 = /index.php;`

Comment: Thanks Richard I get your point. But still if I do not force try files to goes for index.php if it `/` I will never go for index.php.

Comment: If you want the URI `/` to map to `/index.php`, you could try adding another location block: `location = / { index index.php; }`